# window.opener.location is null in IE. Works fine in Chrome.

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(window.opener.location.pathname); if(window.opener.location.pathname.toString() == \"/page.aspx\"){window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();}</script>");
```

This works in Chrome, but in IE I get a mass javascript runtime error saying location is null, seems its somehting to do with opener.

What is the equivalent in IE?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990331/javascript-popup-issue-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use `Response.Write` to add JavaScript to the page. View the page source and you will see that the script is added before any of the HTML markup on the page. That is bad.

You should be using [`RegisterStartUpScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx).

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();
String cstext1 = "alert(window.opener.location.pathname);";
cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "alert", cstext1, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.opener.document.location`:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert(window.opener.document.location.pathname); if(window.opener.document.location.pathname.toString() == \"/page.aspx\"){window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();}</script>");
```

Comment: Im now using this for IE browsers and get this: `Unable to get value of propery "document" object is null or undefined